# MyGet & SymbolSource.org: VS2012 isn't finding the pdb

Tags: nuget, symbol-server, myget

I've created a library on myget (part of ci), and I'm trying to push the symbol sources to symbolsource.org (this is a great service, and I love the idea). This is my first attempt. I've been using the instructions found on the myget site: http://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/symbolsource, but there are some gaps.

Here are the steps I go through. First, I create a nuspec file, and I use "nuget pack -symbol xxx" to create the X.symbols.nupkg and X.nupkg files. This works just fine. I then push them individually to myget and symbolsource. I used the nuget pkg explorer to examine the contents, and they look as I would expect (the src, pdb, and dll show up in the symbols). After doing the push, I can log into symbolsource and I see my packages up there using the instructions found on the myget page.

I used the following command to push to symbolsource:

```
nuget push X.symbols.nupkg $ApiKey -Source http://nuget.gw.SymbolSource.org/MyGet/rootdotnet/
```

I then configure visual studio as instructed: make sure to turn off "enable just my code" and also to turn on symbol servers. I then add to the list of symbol servers the following URL:

```
http://srv.SymbolSource.org/pdb/MyGet/gwatts/XXXXX
```

Where XXXX is a GUID I read off the sumbolsource "Your Account"/"Authentication" "Visual Studio" table entry (myget wasn't at all clear this is what I was supposed to do).

I then try to debug. When I hit something in that library, I get the "No Symbols Loaded" page in VS2012. Under details, there is a dump VS2012's attempt to find the pdb file. I see the following:

```
C:\Users\Gordon\Documents\Code\HVQCDCorrelationStudy\CalcSimpleCorrelationTestNumbers\bin\x86\Debug\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\44463130cd7383cb\LINQToTTree\LINQToTTreeLib\obj\x86\Release\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\WINDOWS\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\WINDOWS\symbols\dll\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\WINDOWS\dll\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\Gordon\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb\9c883e0fa93245c99efd2b92dbfc6dfc1\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\Gordon\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb\9c883e0fa93245c99efd2b92dbfc6dfc1\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\Gordon\Documents\Code\HVQCDCorrelationStudy\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\Gordon\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb\9C883E0FA93245C99EFD2B92DBFC6DFC1\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb not found


SYMSRV:  http://srv.SymbolSource.org/pdb/MyGet/gwatts/XXXXX/LINQToTTreeLib.pdb/9C883E0FA93245C99EFD2B92DBFC6DFC1/LINQToTTreeLib.pdb not found


http://srv.SymbolSource.org/pdb/MyGet/gwatts/XXXXX: Symbols not found on symbol server.
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\Gordon\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb\9C883E0FA93245C99EFD2B92DBFC6DFC1\LINQToTTreeLib.pdb not found


SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/LINQToTTreeLib.pdb/9C883E0FA93245C99EFD2B92DBFC6DFC1/LINQToTTreeLib.pdb not found


http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
```

In short, it looks like it correctly contacts symbolssource.org. But something is failing up there. The 9C883E0FA93245C99EFD2B92DBFC6DFC1 is obviously a hash. I have no idea (??) what hash symbolssource assigned to that library - though I'd love to try to figure it out, as that might be a first step to understanding what is going on.

Basically. I don't know how to proceed with debugging at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Update: As mentioned in the answers below, build something small that can be tested. I've done that, and it works just fine. In doing that I discovered there are some debugging tools up on SymbolSource.org - specifically, when you look at a package in your feed, you can find the "Compilations" link. Click on it. It should show a line for each build type you've uploaded. My packages have nothing associated with that - so I've messed up my nuspec file somehow for symbol generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is a slice of humble pie. Turns out on my build server there was an environment variable conflict. The result was that local build scripts built a symbols file just fine and the build server built one without PDB's in it. Without pdb's, of course, the source server was not able do very much.

One thing I did learn on the way is the NuGet PackageExplorer (https://npe.codeplex.com/). Want you can do is use it to load up the nugget symbols package. Then use the plug-in manager to load in the SymbolesSource plug-in (you'll have to use the market place, but it is all free). This utility would have caught the problem in my packages had I submitted the proper ones to it (my local packages passed with flying colors).

Answer (score 1):

Try to isolate a reproducible scenario (rule out as many other factors as you can). Sounds like your Visual Studio set up is correct, so I'm suspicious for package or compilation issues (e.g. symbols and sources out of sync). Feel free to contact [MyGet support](https://www.myget.org/Support) for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks. Adding more data above as I work towards one.